# Render Angular Component in Kendo UI for jQuery Grid Editor

Tags: jquery, angular, kendo-ui

A bit of background to set the scene. An Angular .NET Core app using Kendo UI for jQuery. First off, I am aware this is not an ideal setup, in terms of using Kendo UI for jQuery in an Angular app, the app has been inherited and I have been told that when the app was created Kendo UI for Angular did not support Grids or Editors or something along those lines. I do know that there is better support for Grids and Editors currently in Kendo UI for Angular and I am driving for the app to veer in that direction, however there is no current scope for me to spend time rebuilding.

**So I pose my question...**

Below is a code snippet of the Kendo UI Grid that I am using which is generated in a function called `createGrid()`. Within the grid on each row there is an `edit` button, clicking the edit button displays a popup/dialog on screen. The popup/dialog html content is placed within `editable > template` which I have omitted as mentioned in snippet comment. Within this template area is where I am trying to add an Angular `component`. However adding  a component in here or even binding does not seem to be picked up by Angular. I can see the `<app-my-component></app-my-component>` in the dev tools elements, but cannot see static content in the Angular component.

I was wondering what I might need to do in order for the component to be rendered as an Angular component. I assume it's being read as plain text or something and that is why it cannot be handled as I intend.

```
createGrid() {
    const self = this;
    kendo.jQuery('#grid')
        .kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                ...
            },
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: {
                input: true,
                numeric: false
            },
            columns: [
                ...
            ],
            toolbar: ...,
            editable: {
                mode: 'popup',
                window: {
                    ...
                },
                template:
                    `
                    // html for grid editor...omitted
                    // **********************************
                    // add angular component here

                    <app-my-component></app-my-component>

                    ************************************>
                    `
            },
            edit(e) {
                ...
            },
            remove(removeEvent) {
                ...
            },
            save(e) {
                ...
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Since your grid is jQuery then the template has to be jQuery based and not an angular component. Your problem is similar to this, https://jpllosa.blogspot.com/2021/11/kendo-grid-using-vue-wrappers-example.html, Here it is Vue but the custom editor is jQuery because there is no way Vue can initialized to an element which does not exist yet.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jpllosa, makes sense.